# Setup 1:1 NAT using pfSense

Tags: firewall, nat, pfsense

pfSense box:

- Public IPs 208.43.30.118-.117
- Private IP : 192.168.1.1

I need to provide 1:1 NAT mapping to a VM in the private network 192.168.1.5

I am unable to get 1:1 NAT working though it should be direct...

The output of

```
$ pfctl -s rules
scrub in on em0 all fragment reassemble
scrub in on em1 all fragment reassemble
anchor "relayd/*" all
block drop in log all label "Default deny rule"
block drop out log all label "Default deny rule"
block drop in quick inet6 all
block drop out quick inet6 all
block drop quick proto tcp from any port = 0 to any
block drop quick proto tcp from any to any port = 0
block drop quick proto udp from any port = 0 to any
block drop quick proto udp from any to any port = 0
block drop quick from <snort2c> to any label "Block snort2c hosts"
block drop quick from any to <snort2c> label "Block snort2c hosts"
block drop in log quick proto carp from (self) to any
pass quick proto carp all keep state
pass quick proto pfsync all keep state
block drop in log quick proto tcp from <sshlockout> to any port = ssh label "sshlockout"
block drop in log quick proto tcp from <webConfiguratorlockout> to any port = http label "webConfiguratorlockout"
block drop in quick from <virusprot> to any label "virusprot overload table"
block drop in log quick on em0 from <bogons> to any label "block bogon networks from WAN"
block drop in on ! em0 inet from 208.43.30.112/29 to any
block drop in inet from 208.43.30.118 to any
block drop in inet from 208.43.30.117 to any
block drop in on ! em1 inet from 192.168.1.0/24 to any
block drop in inet from 192.168.1.1 to any
block drop in on em0 inet6 from fe80::250:56ff:fe8b:571e to any
block drop in on em1 inet6 from fe80::250:56ff:fe8b:571f to any
pass in on lo0 all flags S/SA keep state label "pass loopback"
pass out on lo0 all flags S/SA keep state label "pass loopback"
pass out all flags S/SA keep state allow-opts label "let out anything from firewall host itself"
pass out route-to (em0 208.43.30.113) inet from 208.43.30.118 to ! 208.43.30.112/29 flags S/SA keep state allow-opts label "let out anything from firewall host itself"
pass in quick on em1 proto tcp from any to (em1) port = http flags S/SA keep state label "anti-lockout rule"
anchor "userrules/*" all
pass in quick on em0 reply-to (em0 208.43.30.113) inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.1.5 port = http flags S/SA keep state label "USER_RULE: allow webtraffic"
pass in quick on em1 inet from 192.168.1.0/24 to any flags S/SA keep state label "USER_RULE: Default allow LAN to any rule"
anchor "tftp-proxy/*" all
```

I tried setting it up a few times with port forward as well as 1:1 NAT but traffic does not forward to the internal IP. What am I doing wrong?

Interface External IP   Internal IP     Destination IP  Description

WAN     208.43.30.117   LAN net     192.168.1.5     forward external to internal ip

The additional ip is just an ip alias (Virtual ip)
I had already added the 1:1 NAT rule before uploading the output of command via gui
Why is this not reflected in the output posted

Comment: You do not appear to have any NAT rules in your configuration.  pfSense allows you to configure 1:1 NAT through their GUI - have you tried this?  If you want to do this manually see `man pf.conf` (there are examples of `nat` and `binat` rules - add some to your configuration and tell us what happens)

Answer (score 2):

The mistake i made was not configuring the client's gateway to point to pfsense.

The nat client had multiple network cards and default gateway was set to another network card.

Once it was fixed the issue was resolved